# Could not get unknown property "runtime" Gradle 7.0

Tags: java, gradle

I switched to gradle 7.0 recently and now cannot build my projects jar, with the error

> Could not get unknown property 'runtime' for configuration container of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfigurationContainer.
> `

Here is my build.gradle:

```
    apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'application'



repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {

    implementation group: 'org.glassfish.jersey.containers', name: 'jersey-container-servlet-core', version: '2.7'
    implementation group: 'org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate', name: 'jetty-all', version: '9.3.0.M1'
//
    implementation 'javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:2.3.0'
//    testImplementation group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.11'
    implementation group: 'org.json', name: 'json', version: '20200518'
    implementation group: 'com.jolbox', name: 'bonecp', version: '0.8.0.RELEASE'
    implementation group: 'mysql', name: 'mysql-connector-java', version: '8.0.22'
    implementation group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs', name: 'jackson-jaxrs-json-provider', version: '2.12.0'

    implementation "org.slf4j:slf4j-simple:1.7.9"
}

version = '1.0'

jar {
    manifest {
        attributes(
                'Main-Class': 'classes.RestServer',
        )
    }
}

task fatJar(type: Jar) {
    manifest.from jar.manifest
    classifier = 'all'
    from {
        configurations.runtime.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }
    } {
        exclude "META-INF/.SF"
        exclude "META-INF/.DSA"
        exclude "META-INF/*.RSA"
    }
    with jar
}

artifacts {
    archives fatJar
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Gradle [removed the runtime configuration](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/upgrading_version_6.html#sec:configuration_removal) after Gradle 6.x.

You can either change your `fatJar` task in `build.gradle` to refer to `runtimeConfiguration` (as per the [Java plugin documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_plugin.html#sec:source_set_properties)):

```
task fatJar(type: Jar) {
    manifest.from jar.manifest
    classifier = 'all'
    from {
        // change here: runtimeClasspath instead of runtime
        configurations.runtimeClasspath.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }
    } {
        exclude "META-INF/.SF"
        exclude "META-INF/.DSA"
        exclude "META-INF/*.RSA"
    }
    with jar
}
```

Alternatively use a plugin that deals with fat jar building for you. I've tried [Shadow](https://github.com/johnrengelman/shadow) a few years ago. This should also take care of files with the same names from different jars (like `META-INF/LICENSE`) that you may run into with your approach.

Answer (score 1):

Support for `runtime` configuration has been stopped `gradle-7.0`, so `configurations.runtime` is not working.

Task `copyAllDependencies` worked for me in `gradle-7.0`.

Here is the example to copy dependencies into `${buildDir}/output/libs`:

Add following to `build.gradle`.

```
task copyAllDependencies(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.compileClasspath
    into "${buildDir}/output/libs"
}
build.dependsOn(copyAllDependencies)
```

I hope it helps.