# How to collect all dependencies in Gradle 7?

Tags: gradle, jar, dependencies, build.gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl

With Gradle 6 I used following snippet to collect all dependencies in my project (using `project.configurations.runtime`) and copy them to a folder `"$buildDir/libs"`.

```
tasks.register<Copy>("copyDependenciesToLib") {
    into("$buildDir/libs")
    from(project.configurations.runtime)
    doLast {
        println("copyDependenciesToLib:\n  ${project.configurations.runtime.get().files.joinToString("\n  ") { it.absolutePath }}\n  ->\n  $buildDir/libs")
    }
}
```

I am currently migrating to Gradle 7, and IntelliJ tells me that `runtime` cannot be resolved, it seems that it has been removed from `configuration`?
Can you point me in the right direction to reproduce the behavior of the above script in Gradle 7?

[image: Unresolved reference]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just found the answer myself.

A similar question has been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68133574/could-not-get-unknown-property-runtime-gradle-7-0).

Gradle [has removed the runtime configuration](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/upgrading_version_6.html#sec:configuration_removal) in Gradle 7.

Instead, one can use [`runtimeClasspath`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_plugin.html#tab:configurations).

Our `copy` task now looks the following:

```
tasks.register<Copy>("copyDependenciesToLib") {
    into("$buildDir/libs")
    from(project.configurations.runtimeClasspath)
    doLast {
        println("copyDependenciesToLib:\n  ${project.configurations.runtimeClasspath.get().files.joinToString("\n  ") { it.absolutePath }}\n  ->\n  $buildDir/libs")
    }
}
```